# Vim: is there a way to quickly start in insert mode at a certain line number after erasing that line?

Tags: vim

I personally prefer nano over vim because vim just works so much differently than a standard text editor...it can really be stressful if you don't understand how to use it efficiently.

However, today i was wondering if vim made it possible to do this: you have numbering enabled, and you are in the default/normal mode. You see a line that you want to get rid of , yet replace with different text. Is there a command to start you in insert mode at that particular line automatically? Would you be able to erase that line with `123dd` before that? Just to be clear, what i'm asking is if you can enter the line number then hit some key and wind up in insert mode right there. I know that you could press "123G Enter" then i, but i'm wondering if there's a way to enter the line number, then hit one key on your keyboard to get there and switch modes, i know that hitting `123i` does not work because i just tried it...

Comment: There's not (out of the box) a "Go here _and_ start typing text" in one keystroke, because generally vim works in what I think of as short "sentences". `ci"` for example is "Change inside double-quotes", or `22G` is "Go to line 22".  One sentence would do one _thing_, and here you are asking to do to _things_ (to wit: move the cursor to a line, and change the contents of that line). One of your examples would be "delete the next 123 lines" for `123dd`.  `123i` simply puts you into insert mode because "put me into insert mode 123 times" would be functionally be the same as just once.

Comment: Well good thing i didn't hit ```123dd``` then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For line *n*, `nGC`.  `G` to Go to the start of a line by number, and `C` to Change the contents of the entire line starting at the cursor (which you have just placed at the start of the chosen line), which puts you into Insert mode.

Comment: Wow! That did exactly what i described in the question...the reason i haven't entirely given up on vim is that it's such an enormous program, just cuz i don't know how to do something doesn't mean it can't be done...